# Как изменить одну половину текста и вторую?

Tags: php

Да, знаю, заголовок звучит абсурдно, но послушайте. Вот например есть никнейм “elinocide” нужно чтобы после некоторых действий он превратился в "§celino§fcide"
И допустим есть ник "Sencon" нужно чтобы стало "§cSen§fcon". И так нужно с любым ником, вне зависимости от того какой он, или сколько в нем букв. как сделать такую некую конвертацию чтоли, и возможно ли это вообще? Надеюсь вы меня поняли:)

Comment: Море вариантов.. Хоть со строкой работать, хоть конвертировать в массив, вставлять новые и обратно, и т.п...

Answer (score 2):

```
function getSomethingStrange($string) {
    $strHalfPos = ceil(strlen($string) / 2);
    $firstSign = '§c';
    $secondSign = '§f';
    
    return $firstSign . substr($string, 0, $strHalfPos) . $secondSign  . substr($string, $strHalfPos);
}

echo getSomethingStrange('elinocide');
echo getSomethingStrange('Sencon');

// §celino§fcide
// §cSen§fcon
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @elinocide пожалуйста! Галочку тык